# Экспорт FlowDocument в DOC(x) или XLS

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, export, office, c#

В общем у меня есть программа на WPF, в ней я генерирую отчеты на основе неких динамических данных в FlowDocument, а затем отображаю из с помощью контрола - DocumentViewer. Теперь мне осталось сделать экспорт этого отчета в различные форматы, с помощью iTextSharp появилась возможность сохранять в PDF, а так же нативными способами могу сохранить документ в XPS.

Подскажите, как сохранить FlowDocument в вордовском, а еще лучше и экселевском, форматах.
Или посоветуйте либу на С# для перевода из PDF/XPS в DOC, пол инета перерыл, нахожу только обратную конвертацию из doc в xps, а наоборот ничего найти не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге сделал с помощью библиотеки [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/), достаточно мощная и очень простая библиотека, намного проще с ней работать чем с Simple OOXML, рекомендую!

Answer (score 1):

Сохранение из FlowDocument в DOCX и XLSX можно сделать на основе [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb448854.aspx), а конкретно с помощью библиотеки-обертки - [Simple OOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/48673).

Плюс по Excel могут пригодиться: [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) и [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/).

Comment: Спасибо, поковыряю завтра, надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Я делала сохранение в RTF с помощью TextRange.

```
TextRange sourceDocument = new TextRange(myFlowDocument.ContentStart, myFlowDocument.ContentEnd);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
sourceDocument.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
stream.Position = 0;
myCreateFileFromStream(fileName, stream);
```

Но это RTF. В RTF, например, не работают пропорциональные размеры для колонок таблицы Width="2*".

Используя библиотеку DocX, вы заново создаете отчет в DocX и сохраняете его в doc или в библиотеке DocX предусмотрена конвертация из FlowDocument в DocX?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: С помощью DocX я заного создавал отчет и сохранял в doc.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Тогда мне этот вариант не подходит - у меня много отчетов и не хочется делать каждый отчет в двух вариантах (в FlowDocument и в DocX).